# Android Notification click event run chain of activities

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

My application has notifications for incoming messages. I have a tabActivity for mainly it runs after some several activities.

My question is *How can I open a specific tab when I click notification ?*.

For example :

```
A----->B------>C------->D ------> Specific Tab
```

**Note** : A,B,C are normal activities and D is a Tab activity

Comment: passing bundle throughout the chain of activities to the correct activity thats how I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean taskbar notification? if yes you can use pending intents to do the trick

I had some problwm with the same thing Check this link

[Cannot Send data Through pendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390733/cannot-send-data-through-pendingintent)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

Answer (score 0):

how i did it was by using *putExtra()* and *getExtra()* while starting each activity and passing on ahead.. The format is sort of

From your GCMBroadCastIntent:

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,A.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("setFragment", "D");
```

In A *onCreate()*:

```
 if (getIntent()!=null  && getIntent().getExtras()!=null 
        && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("setFragment")); 
     if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("setFragment").equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
             mainIntent.putExtra("setFragment", "D");
         startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Similarly for B,C :
From C navigate to D.

Check for the intent and perform required actions in the *onCreate()* of C to reach D.